# How to provide service mock in SpectatorRouting

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, spectator

I implemented a test using Spectator for the Angular component. Try to find a solution to mocking service with `SpectatorRouting`. I have simple service like the below:

```
export class ProductService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getProduct(productId: string): Observable<Product>;
}
```

and I have the component like below:

```
export class ProductComponent {
  product$: Observable<boolean | Product>;

  readonly routes = routes;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private router: Router
  ) {

    this.product$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      map((params) => params.get('id')),
      switchMap((val) => productService.getProduct(val)),
      catchError(() => this.router.navigate([routes.notFoundPage]))
    );
  }
}
```

and I can't find a pretty solution to return value by method mock ProductService. I implement a solution but this is ugly :(.

```
const productService = {
  getProduct: () => of({}),
};

describe('ProductComponentSpectator', () => {
  let spectator: SpectatorRouting<ProductComponent>;
  const createComponent = createRoutingFactory({
    component: ProductComponent,
    params: { id: '100' },
    declarations: [
      MainProductComponent,
      DetailsProductComponent,
      SpanTooltipComponent,
    ],
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
    providers: [mockProvider(ProductService, productService)],
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn(productService, 'getProduct').and.returnValue(of(getProduct()));
    spectator = createComponent();
  });

  it('should get brand name', () => {
    expect(spectator.query('.product-brand')).toHaveExactText('Asus');
  });
});

function getProduct(): Product {
  return {
    productId: '100',
    brand: 'Asus',
  } as Product;
}
```

I have doubt with this solution, for me, it is a strange approach with creating const service on top of the test and next spyOn the same method. My intuition tells me, that this mock should be defined completely in providers (with method etc). Spectator probably provides a more friendly approach to mocking service for SpectatorRouting, but I didn't find it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to mock it - you can additionally install [ng-mocks](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockProvider) package for that, then you would not need `spyOn` and `getProduct`.

```js
describe('ProductComponentSpectator', () => {
  let spectator: SpectatorRouting<ProductComponent>;
  const createComponent = createRoutingFactory({
    component: ProductComponent,
    params: { id: '100' },
    declarations: [
      MainProductComponent,
      DetailsProductComponent,
      SpanTooltipComponent,
    ],
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
    providers: [
      // MockProvider from ng-mocks (capital M)
      MockProvider(ProductService, {
        getProduct: () => of({
          productId: '100',
          brand: 'Asus',
        } as Product),
      }),
    ],
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    spectator = createComponent();
  });

  it('should get brand name', () => {
    expect(spectator.query('.product-brand')).toHaveExactText('Asus');
  });
});
```